# How do I implement this? $example2.arctext({radius: 400, dir: -1})

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to put

```
$example2.arctext({radius: 400, dir: -1})
```

into my index.html to recreate something like this  http://tympanus.net/Development/Arctext/#sub4 on my site

How do I do that?  :-)

Comment: See the answer to this question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18614/style-guide-for-questions-and-answers

Comment: In case it's not clear, @Austin is objecting to the phrasing of your question (i.e., the language you use). It's also poor form to put code in the title of the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You include their [arctext.js](http://tympanus.net/Development/Arctext/js/jquery.arctext.js) and then use jquery to select your div with text and apply their function...

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://tympanus.net/Development/Arctext/js/jquery.arctext.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="example">Here is curved text></div>

    <script>
        $().ready(function() {
            $('#example').arctext({radius: 300});
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F5fww/1/) for a working example

Answer (score 2):

Follow the directions given here: http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/01/24/arctext-js-curving-text-with-css3-and-jquery/